# How can I switch cameras in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, icelink

My app uses Xamarin.Forms. Now I am trying to apply IceLink for implementing video calls. Is there a way to switch between front/rear/anyOther camera? I saw a sample where LocalMediaStream's UseNextVideoDevice() method is used, but now LocalMediaStream is obsolete, and I don't have it. But I do have IceLink.FM.LocalMedia object in my PageModel.

```
    public void SwitchCamera()
    {
        if (_localMedia == null)
            return;
  //    _localMedia.UseNextVideoDevice(); // obsolete
    }
```

Is it possible to make that switch between cameras?

Comment: https://help.frozenmountain.com/docs/icelink3/faq/common-questions/how-do-i-switch-the-audio-or-video-capture-device

Comment: @Jason Thank you very much for your comment. I have seen this, but ChangeVideoSourceInput() requires a parameter of type SourceInput. Should I get all available cameras from GetVideoSourceInputs()? Unfortunately, in emulator this method returns only null.

Comment: a cursory look at the API docs shows that LocalMedia has a VideoSources collection

Comment: @Jason Thank you again. If you make it an answer, I will mark it as such.